# valueerror invalid literal for int () with base 10 django in migrate, when deploying django project in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'owner',null=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        current_user = current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)
    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        current_user = current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)


class Post(models.Model):
    post=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def queryset(self):
        return super(UserProfileManager,self).get(queryset).filter(city='surat')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',blank=True)

    surat = UserProfileManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from tutorial import views
from accounts.forms import Registrationform,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import Post,Friend

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/home.html'
    def get(self,request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts=Post.objects.all()
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend =Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()
        args={
        'form':form,'posts':posts,'users':users,'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form  = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.user=request.user
            post.save()
            text =form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('accounts:home')
        args = {'form' : form,'text' : text}
        return render(request, self.template_name,args)


def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    new_friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user,  new_friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user,  new_friend)
    return redirect ('accounts:home')




def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('please fill all the fields and make sure new password must be match')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        args={'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)

@login_required
def view_profile(request,pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
         user = request.user
    args = {'user' : user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("please go back and write correct values")
        else:
            form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
    else:
        HttpResponse("hllo")
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("password does not match,go back and try again")
        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/change_password.html',args)
    else:
        return redirect ('/accounts/login')
```

form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from django.forms import RegistrationForm,EditProfileForm
from django import forms
from accounts.models import Post

class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder'  : 'write a post'


    }
    ))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post',)


class Registrationform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        )
    def save(self,commit=True):
        user=super(Registrationform,self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name= self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email=self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    #template_name = '/something/else'
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'password'
         )
```

and the error is

```
(.vEnv) jayu@broadwell-gt2:~/Desktop/tutorial$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.0.82 to 7.0.83
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ jaysuthar... up, run.5398 (Free)
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, contenttypes, auth, admin, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying accounts.0002_auto_20180514_0523...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 482, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 564, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 720, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Django keeps throwing the following when I deploying project (error is in migrate time when i run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`)

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

i want to deploy this project on heroku, it successfully run till

```
git push heroku master --forc
```

but when i migrate database with this command :

```
    heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

it gives error of valueerror.

where i did mistake ?

If you can provide any help I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT :

accounts.0002_auto_20180514_0523 file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9 on 2018-05-14 05:23
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userprofile',
            name='phone',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: It pretty clearly states there is some int literal that was left empty.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek But where is state as  empty ? How can I solve this error ?

Comment: Open migration file in question (`accounts.0002_auto_20180514_0523`) and find where migration is trying to add `''` to integer field.

Comment: @Borut i have added that file in question. pleas help me to find where migration trying to add ' ' in integer field.

Comment: @JaySuthar the only relevant parts of your code (for this question) are the UserProfile model definition, the migration file and the traceback. You should edit out other models and all views and forms code, they only add noise actually.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in it's first version your UserProfile's "phone" field was a CharField defaulting to the empty string. Changing an existing field's type requires a three-steps migrations: first create a new field with the desired type, create and apply the migration, then create a datamigration that will copy original data to the new field with proper transformations, error handling etc, and finally delete the original field (create and apply the migration).

BUT : in your case, making this field an integer is just plain wrong. A phone number is **NOT** an integer. First because you cannot add, substract, multiply or divide phone numbers, then because a phone number can contain non-numeric characters too (cf international phone numbers formats).

Thinking that everything made of numeric characters should be an int is a common beginner mistake (just like using floats instead of decimals for prices storage and calculations). When in doubt, ask yourself whether applying mathematical operations would make sense...

Comment: Didn't work after removing phone field .still getting same error.

Comment: that was to be expected if you kept the migration raising the exception... you have to go back to the original model definition and delete the migration.